# Sweetalert2 tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have a question, is it possible to add a tooltip to the alert?
Or some alternative tooltip

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: '<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>',
  icon: 'info',
  html: 'You can use <b>bold text</b>, ' +
    '<a href="//sweetalert2.github.io">links</a> ' +
    'and other HTML tags',
  showCloseButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  focusConfirm: false,
  confirmButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Great!',
  confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs up, great!',
  cancelButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
  cancelButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs down'
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: Where do you want your tool tip to be displayed? Because you can add browser integrated tooltip literally everywhere as long as it is an HTML element. And as you can see from the snippet in your question, there are lots of HTML element that you can specify

Comment: There could be a tooltip in the text in the "other" element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using simple HTML CSS would definitely work. Here's a solution to get the required output just with HTML and CSS try the code below,

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: '<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>',
  icon: 'info',
  html: 'You can use <b>bold text</b>, ' +
    '<a href="//sweetalert2.github.io">links</a> ' +
    'and other HTML tags' +
    '<br><br><button class="tool-tip btn" title-new="this is how it look like">Hover here to check</button>',
  showCloseButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  focusConfirm: false,
  confirmButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Great!',
  confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs up, great!',
  cancelButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
  cancelButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs down'
})
```

```css
 button {
        padding:10px;
      } 
      .tool-tip[title-new]:hover:after {
          content: attr(title-new);
          position: absolute;
          border: #c0c0c0 1px dotted;
          padding: 10px;
          display: block;
          z-index: 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
          background-color: #000000;
          color: #ffffff;
          max-width: 200px;
          text-decoration: none;
          text-align:center;
        margin-top:5px;
        margin-left:50px;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```